# Laravel exists() ignores soft deleted rows

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am building up an Eloquent query in Laravel 5.5. All I want to know is whether a row exists in the database - I want to include any soft deleted rows:

```
$query = Thing::where([
      'date' => $date,
      'user_id' => $userId
      ]);

return $query->exists();
```

My problem is that this is ignoring soft deleted rows, so that it will return `false` if a soft deleted row with the given `date` and `user_id` exists. Is there a neat way to include soft deleted rows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use `Thing::withTrashed()->where(...)`.

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models